# SafeArea backwards compatibility

Tags: ios, swift, safearealayoutguide, uiedgeinsets

I'm having an issue when trying to layout a view programatically and I cant seem to find a concise, non hacky way to fix it.

I'm using safeAreaInsets to size some elements in my view. This works well until I try it out on a pre iOS 11 device. Obviously, with the lack of safeAreaInsets the sizing of my subviews falls apart and everything becomes a mess. What do I fall back to when using older versions of iOS.

More specifically, what can I implement in the extension below that will work as expected?

```
extension UIView {

func compatibilityInsets() -> UIEdgeInsets {
        if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
            return self.safeAreaInsets
        } else {
            //what goes here?
            return self.olderVersionOfInsets
        }
    }
}
```

Here is an exmaple of how I might use this extension method:

```
var minimumHeaderHeight: CGFloat {
    //allows the header height to be 70 below navigation bar
    return 70 + view.compatibilityInsets().top
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`safeAreaInsets` was added to help avoid content disappearing behind the "notch" in the iPhone X... which only supports iOS 11 IIRC.

So the alternative for iOS 10 and below would be `return .zero` as there doesn't need to be any safe area defined.

`.zero` in this case is inferred to be of type `UIEdgeInsets` so is equivalent to calling `UIEdgeInsets.zero`.